# What Control Do I Get When Ordering a Webserver

Tags: web-services, odbc, hosting

I tried using the live chat of the host but got nowhere.

Long story short - got a php api communicating to MSSQL 2012, recent ODBC 18.2, 18.1(?) no longer connects with MSSQL 2012 as well as PHP PDO drivers are necessary.

I wanted to make sure that I can install these myself before ordering a webserver host, or is that generally what comes as standard, already installed?

Nik. :)

Contacted sales - got nowhere.